# Order the result for listing child in pydrive

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
def get_children(root_folder_id):
    str = "\'" + root_folder_id + "\'" + " in parents and trashed=false"
    file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': str}).GetList()
    return file_list
```

could we force the file list to be ordered in someway (alphabetical, last date modified, etc)

Comment: could you please share only the list data you want to be sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `orderBy` as your [optional parameters](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list#parameters) for your file list function.

### orderBy

- A comma-separated list of sort keys.
- Valid keys are `'createdDate', 'folder', 'lastViewedByMeDate', 'modifiedByMeDate', 'modifiedDate', 'quotaBytesUsed', 'recency', 'sharedWithMeDate', 'starred', 'title', and 'title_natural'`.
- Each key sorts ascending by default, but may be reversed with the `'desc'` modifier.

---

**Example usage:**
?orderBy=folder,modifiedDate desc,title. Please note that there is a current limitation for users with approximately one million files in which the requested sort order is ignored.

```
#Order based on modified date in descending order
drive.ListFile({'orderBy': 'modifiedDate desc'}).GetList()
```